# How to change code on the front page of a Magento store?

Tags: php, magento

I am helping out with a Magento store initially configured by another developer who is now gone from the company, and I have no experience using Magento at all.  Instead of using the built-in newsletter tools, he created an HTML form which points to a completely different server (which he owns) and now we no longer get notifications when a customer signs up for it.

Somehow, he embedded the HTML into the front page of the Store's website.  I spent hours looking for the HTML and did find it, in a page called "Subscribe.phtml".  I got happy, changed the code inside that page to what I want it to be, uploaded it back to the server and... nothing.  No change at all to the site. I flushed the cache but that did not help.

The page does not appear to have much code in it.  In CMS->Pages->Content, it shows only this:

```
{{block type="featuredproductslider/featuredproductslider" name="featuredproductslider"
template="magentothem/featuredproductslider/featuredproductslider.phtml"}}{{block 
type="newproduct/newproduct" name="newproduct" 
template="magentothem/newproduct/newproduct.phtml"}}
```

Under Design, it shows only that the layout is "3 columns". There is literally nothing else in this section.

Can you help me understand how I can change the HTML in this area to make this work?  If this is helpful, here's a picture of the area that I am trying to configure:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you have not found the correct source as the changes you have made do not affect the site.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Is there any way to figure out where that code comes from?  Maybe some way to dig into the xml files?  I agree that I haven't found the right thing yet, but I'm at a loss right now as to where it might be.

Comment: Find the magento users guide ( you should be able to google it and it is a PDF document) and in there it describes to how set your front end up so that it will tell you where to find each section in your code.

Comment: Thank you, but I've gone through that and it's not just a matter of RTFM. And honestly, I am not looking to learn the entire Magento setup.  I just want to know if there's a path I can follow that will get me to the point where this code comes from.  I am sure it's in the manual - if there's a specific page that I should look at, please point me at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On page 44 of the [manual](http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/MagentoDesignGuide.pdf), there's a section called "How to find out which layout file to modify". I used Template Hints and figured out where the code lived. This is what Jim was referring to.  It would have been nice for someone to instruct me on how to do this.

I set it up and found that the previous developer had modified the template directly rather than use blocks or other parts built-in to the system to modify the front page.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable template hints in the Magento configuration:

1. Go to System->Configuration
2. Change "Current Configuration Scope" to "Main Website"
3. Go to Advanced->Developer
4. Under the Debug tab, choose "Yes" for the "Template Path Hints"
5. Save configuration.

Now go to your homepage, refresh the page and you will see paths to all templates used on the homepage. You will then get a good idea of where each block comes from.

It won't solve your problem, but it might help you find the right template to edit.